# Get NFTs by collection address and owner

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, react

I'm trying to get all the NFTs in a collection that a wallet owns, but I only achieved get all the NFTs of a collection, or all the NFTs of a wallet (multi collections).

```
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react"
import { Metaplex, walletAdapterIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js"

...

const walletAdapter = useWallet()
const { connection } = useConnection()
const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(walletAdapterIdentity(walletAdapter))

// Get all NFTs of my collection
const candyMachine = await metaplex
   .candyMachinesV2()
   .findByAddress({ address: new PublicKey(candyMachineAddress) })

// Get all NFTs of wallet (My collection and others)
const walletNFTs = await metaplex
   .nfts()
   .findAllByOwner({ owner: wallet.publicKey })
```

Is this filter possible? I was exploring Metaplex SDK, but I didn't find this type of filter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering for a collection address, something like the following

```
   // using metaplex SDK to fetch all NFTs of connected wallet
    const nfts = await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .findAllByOwner({ owner: wallet.publicKey })
     

    // filter for nfts in "collection"
    let nft = []
    for (let i = 0; i < nfts.length; i++) {
      if (nfts[i].collection?.address.toString() == collectionAddress.toString()) {
        nft.push(nfts[i])
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. But I wonder if there is a way to get this NFTs without a custom filter. If the user has hundreds of NFTs, I need to get all of them to show a few. I was finding a more performance way. It seems Metaplex doesn't have a method to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can now achieve this using the DAS API on your RPC provider (although not sure if every RPC provider supports it). Use the `searchAssets` method with `ownerAddress` and `grouping` params.

Here's an example payload to POST to your RPC endpoint:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "my-id",
    "method": "searchAssets",
    "params": {
        "ownerAddress": "GsXriSHaN6PK4oeP9W8kXqYHJS8JX3Hac7PUABKuWbrK",
        "grouping": [
            "collection",
            "BUjZjAS2vbbb65g7Z1Ca9ZRVYoJscURG5L3AkVvHP9ac"
        ],
        "page": 1,
        "limit": 500
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns an array of [Metadata](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/c171e1e31d9fe12852afb39e449123339848180e/packages/js/src/plugins/nftModule/models/Metadata.ts#L12) object that has a collection field. You can filter the NFTs that match the collection you're looking for.

```
const walletNFTs = await metaplex
   .nfts()
   .findAllByOwner({ owner: wallet.publicKey })
```

Comment: As I said in the other comment, this way it works. However, it is not very performant.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Alchemy getnfts method. It gives all the NFTs for a wallet.
https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnfts